Unable to compile Apollo in iOS with Xcode 16.1 - Missing run-bundled-codegen.sh
I’m working on an iOS project using Apollo with GraphQL in Xcode 16.1, and I’ve encountered an issue that prevents me from building my project correctly. When I try to build the app, I get the following error:
Cannot find run-bundled-codegen.sh
What happens is that after adding Apollo to my project using Swift Package Manager (SPM), I don’t have the run-bundled-codegen.sh file, which is apparently required for the code generation process.
Steps I followed
I added Apollo Client to my project using SPM, following the official documentation.
The installation seemed to complete correctly, but the run-bundled-codegen.sh file is not being downloaded, which is needed to generate the code corresponding to the GraphQL queries.
I tried to build and run the project, but I get the mentioned error since the run-bundled-codegen.sh file is not present in the project.
How should I fix this?
I’ve checked the documentation and some forums but couldn’t find a clear solution that works with the version of Xcode (16.1) I’m using. Has anyone encountered the same issue or knows how to resolve it?
My setup
Xcode: 16.1
iOS SDK: 16.1
Apollo Client: Using the latest Apollo version via SPM.
Error: Missing the run-bundled-codegen.sh file.
What I’ve tried so far:
Reinstalling Apollo: The file still doesn’t appear.
Cleaning the project: Didn’t resolve the issue.
Checking SPM configuration: Everything seems fine, but the file is still not downloading.
